# Back end server update files in Android Asset folder

Tags: android, server, backend

I am new to android. Here is my question , is there any ways to update android asset folder from server. For example, I have empty name.txt file in asset folder in my android studio. I want the name.txt file get update the data from backend server. Is that possible ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not from server. Or what else.

Files in assets are not updatable/writable as they are read only.

Well the assets directory is read only.

Comment: Thank you. Any other solutions ?

Comment: Not for updating files in assets. But you could copy those files to private internal memory. There you can update them.

Comment: Noted with Thank you.